# firebase auth in valid authentication error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

facing the error "[firebase_auth/invalid-verification-is]" while trying to achieve Firebase phone auth in my flutter Application.

The web version of the app is working fine, but the mobile app is throwing error.

SDK version for flutter is: 3.3.2

Comment: Share the code that is causing the issue please.

Comment: check firebase console that you have all the settings correctly done or not?

Answer (score 1):

Android:

1. If you haven't already set your app's `SHA-1` hash in the Firebase console, do so.`./gradlew signingReport`.
2. To use phone number authentication, Firebase must be able to verify that phone number sign-in requests are coming from your app. There are two ways Firebase Authentication accomplishes [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification)

iOS:

1. In Xcode, enable push notifications for your project
2. ensure your APNs authentication key is configured with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and  [Start receiving silent notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#start-receiving-silent-notifications).

Comment: Adding APN did the trick for me. Using iOS only at the moment,.. probably have to do the SHA-1 when using Android.

Comment: best of luck @Cyber